# In windows shell, how to let the batch file understand %0 as is?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file in windows, where "%0" needs to be understood as "%0" instead of the name of the batch file. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may use the "escape" trickery, whereby **%**, preceded by another **%**, will be treated like a literal:

```
%%0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... Just googled it.
Use double percent signs.

"%%0" will be fine.